# Unable to understand the last part of the solution

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

After seeing this question, my head went boom for a second.

So, I have two questions:

1)How did they approach this question? How did they start thinking in that direction? Should I memorise the process or is there any intuition sort of thing?

2)I could not understand the last part of the solution where they said that we can obtain the same thing by eliminating m and n. How should I do that?

Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: If you don't mind, would you tell me which book is this?

Comment: I wouldn't mind a bit, dear. The book is S.N. Dey class XI maths.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your first question, but I can (sort of) answer your second question:

From (1), we can also get

$$
(m + m'\cos\theta)^2 + {m'}^2 - {m'}^2 \cos^2 \theta = 1
$$

or

$$
(m + m'\cos\theta)^2 = 1 - {m'}^2 \sin^2 \theta
$$

Similarly, from (2) we can also get

$$
(n + n'\cos\theta)^2 = 1 - {n'}^2 \sin^2 \theta
$$

These equations are basically (4) and (5) except that the positions of $m, n$ and $m', n'$ are interchanged. Do you see how to proceed from here?

Comment: I see! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, let $a=m, b = m', c = n, d = n'$.

Then :

$$
(b+a\cos\theta)^2 + a^2(1-\cos^2\theta)=a^2+b^2+2ab\cos\theta=1
\\
(d+c\cos\theta)^2 + c^2(1-\cos^2\theta)=c^2+d^2+2cd\cos\theta=1
\\
\implies 
(b+a\cos\theta)^2 = 1-a^2\sin^2\theta
\\
(d+c\cos\theta)^2 = 1-c^2\sin^2\theta
$$
Multiplying these equations, we get :
$$
(b+a\cos\theta)^2(d+c\cos\theta)^2 = (1-a^2\sin^2\theta)(1-c^2\sin^2\theta)
$$
Now, $$
(b+a\cos\theta)(d+c\cos\theta)=bd+\cos\theta(ad+bc)+ac\cos^2\theta
\\
=bd+\cos\theta(ad+bc)+ac(1-\sin^2\theta)
\\
=bd+ac+\cos\theta(ad+bc)-ac\sin^2\theta
\\
=0-ac\sin^2\theta=-ac\sin^2\theta
$$
Substituting this in the first equation :
$$
a^2c^2sin^4\theta=(1-a^2\sin^2\theta)(1-c^2\sin^2\theta)
\\
\implies a^2+c^2=\csc^2\theta
$$ 
In the same way, this can be proved to be equal to $b^2+d^2$ in the following manner :
$$
(a+b\cos\theta)^2 = 1-b^2\sin^2\theta
\\
(c+d\cos\theta)^2 = 1-d^2\sin^2\theta
\\
(a+b\cos\theta)^2(c+d\cos\theta)^2 = (1-b^2\sin^2\theta)(1-d^2\sin^2\theta)
$$
Simplifying as above :
$$
(a+b\cos\theta)(c+d\cos\theta)=ac+\cos\theta(bc+ad)+bd(1-\sin^2\theta)=-bd\sin^2\theta
\\
b^2d^2\sin^4\theta=(1-b^2\sin^2\theta)(1-d^2\sin^2\theta)
\\
\implies b^2+d^2=csc^2\theta
$$